# Function not returning switched list

Tags: python

I'm working on the travelling salesman problem with simulated annealing and need to write a function that swaps two elements in a list (list contains destinations to which the salesperson travels to, I have assumed that he starts at the same city to which he returns). I've included the code below:

```
def new_walk(old_walk):
    n1 = rand.randint(1, len(old_walk)-2)
    n2 = rand.randint(1, len(old_walk)-2)
    walk = old_walk
    walk[n1], walk[n2] = walk[n2], walk[n1]
    return walk
```

n1 and n2 are two integers corresponding to the two random list indices I want to switch, the reasoning behind `len(old_cycle)-2` in the max value of the `randint` function is that I don't want to switch the last point with any other. 
If I include a print statement within the function definition it gives the correct result, two elements of old_cycle switched. However once I return it to the main function it gives back the old_cycle list. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should post the code from the main portion of the code. I think that's where the issue is.

Comment: You actually don't copy when you do `walk = old_walk`, you'd need to add `[:]`

Comment: Thanks for all the reply guys. @ezdazuzena that gave me the desired result

Comment: The code should still work, even though a shallow/deep copy was not made of the list. It will affect the original list argument in its parent environment, though, which may produce unintended behavior (and vice-versa).

Answer (score 2):

I've tried use my python shell, for which the version is 3.5.2, however the result shows your code works very well. Purely based on the python programming, I strongly suggest you to use the `walk = old_walk[:]` copy a list.

Comment: Oh sweet, that did it. How come simply setting `walk  = old_walk` did not work?

Comment: python is a dynamic programming language, which means you don't need specifically define the data type before you use, the interpreter will automatically do it for you. However, it exists some hazards, it will sometimes mix up the types of those variables. For your case, I think your python interpreter probably mingled the namespaces.

Comment: @DamianAnslik read about name binding in python. it has nothing to do with the "python interpreter mingling namespaces", which is not a thing.

Comment: @acushner, I happen to find that you are correct. Here are some things about the python `list` [readHere](http://henry.precheur.org/python/copy_list). In summary, if someone directly uses `new_list = old_list` to copy a `list`, then both the `new_list` and the `old_list` **probably** will refer to same the memory address, so modify either one will cause change of the other one. However, I think this is not a wide issue among different python versions, or to be exact, different systems and installations.